# MFC multibyte application shows junk "????" on pasting Chinese characters, but typing works

Tags: unicode, localization, mfc, multibyte

Our MFC application uses Multi Byte Character Set (MBCS). OS is Windows 7.

We could type in Chinese Simplified characters by virtual keyboard, but copy pasting Chinese characters from Google Translate to an edit box in the application shows junk characters "????"

Is this a known issue with MBCS applications? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

When copying and pasting into a multi-byte app the Unicode characters will be converted into the local code page. If they can't be converted you'll get ?. You really should be compiling and distributing your app in Unicode otherwise you'll be fighting these sorts of issues all the time.

If you can't re-compile in Unicode try catching the 'Paste' action and handle the clipboard yourself. Use `GetClipboardData` and read the value for `CF_UNICODETEXT`, which will be the valid text. You'll then need to do your own conversion to the correct multi-byte format.

Comment: Tx. Our app is huge. So, compiling in unicode is the last thing. Any workarounds please?

Comment: Possibly (see edited answer) but you'll have to do Unicode at some point so why not do the work now instead of wasting time with work-arounds.